# C compiling error with homemade library

Tags: c, header, include, prototype

it has been several years since the last time I wrote in C so I am sure the error I get is very stupid even so I thoroughly checked the search engine. Sorry in advance if that is the case.

The program I am writing is getting bigger and bigger so I decided to export some basic functions into a homemade library "stackmat.c"
Here is the code with two functions,
stackmat.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
//#include "stackmat.h"

double *stackmat(double *A, int sizeA[2], int dim)
// dim = 0, output is 1 row of sizeA[0] elements
// dim = 1, output is 0 column of sizeA[1] elements
{   double *B;
    int i;
    B = calloc(sizeA[dim],sizeof(double));
    if (dim == 1)           // size sizeA[1]
    {   for (i=0; i<sizeA[0]*sizeA[1]; i++) B[i%sizeA[1]] += A[i];
    }
    else                // size sizeA[0]
    {   for (i=0; i<sizeA[0]*sizeA[1]; i++) B[i/sizeA[1]] += A[i];
    }
    return B;
}

double *SumMat(double *A, double *B, int sizeA[2], int sizeB[2])
{   int i;
    double *C;
    C = calloc(sizeA[0]*sizeA[1],sizeof(double));
    for (i=0; i<sizeA[0]*sizeA[1]; i++) C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    return C;
}
```

The header
stackmat.h

```
#ifndef STACKMAT_H_INCLUDED
#define STACKMAT_H_INCLUDED

double *stackmat(double *A, int sA[2], int dim)
double *SumMat(double *A, double *B, int sizeA[2], int sizeB[2])

#endif
```

And a simple calling program
checkslantlib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stackmat.h"

void main()
{   double *A, *B;
    int i, sA[2] = {4,3};
    A = malloc(12*sizeof(double));
    for (i=0; i<12; i++)    A[i] = (double) 0.5+i;
    for (i=0; i<12; i++)    printf(" %.1f",A[i]);
    B = stackmat(A,sA,1);
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) printf(" %.1f",B[i]);
}
```

When compiling with "gcc -c stackmat.c", everything is fine.
But "gcc checkslantlib.c -o stackmat.o" returns an error that I cannot understand

```
checkslantlib.c: In function ‘stackmat’:
checkslantlib.c:6: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
checkslantlib.c:13: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
```

If I include the header call in the library, this time it's the library compiling that returns pretty much the same error.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Aren't the Semicolons missing at the end of the decls in Stackmat.h ?

Comment: It's unfortunate that the error of using `void main()` is commonly not diagnosed. `int main(void)` is the correct form. `void main()` is useful (a) in some embedded systems, and (b) for detecting textbooks and tutorials whose authors do not know the C language as well as they think they do. I don't know where the idea started; the very same 1989 standard that introduced the `void` keyword also stated that `int` is the correct return type for `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing semicolons after the function definitions.

```
#ifndef STACKMAT_H_INCLUDED
#define STACKMAT_H_INCLUDED

double *stackmat(double *A, int sA[2], int dim);
double *SumMat(double *A, double *B, int sizeA[2], int sizeB[2]);

#endif
```

It's not giving an error when you compile stackmat.c because you have the #include commented out.

Comment: ok, it's working, thanks everyone. I knew that was a stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

`-o` specifies the output file. Never mind what `gcc` does to your existing stackmat.o, you need to include stackmat.o in compliation by doing:

`> gcc checkslantlib.c stackmat.o -o checkslantlib`

or having in compiled as well as

`> gcc checkslantlib.c stackmat.c -o checkslantlib`

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but what semi-colons exactly? I though prototype didn't need them.

Answer (score 0):

The two files should be compiled separately:

`gcc -c stackmat.c` producing `stackmat.o`

`gcc -c checkslantlib.c` producing `checkslantlib.o`

Then you link them together to produce the final executable:

`gcc -o myprogram checkslantlib.o stackmat.o`

Also check the missing semicolons as mentioned in other answers & comments.